# -sh: java: not found using Oracle JDK 14

Tags: java, linux, shell, sh, executable

I'm trying to install JDK 14 on my linux machine. It's running SliTaz. I got the tar.gz file, and I moved it to the /usr/lib/jvm folder. I've done everything required with linking, etc.

Though when I run the java command it doesn't work. It also doesn't work when I run it in the jvm/jdk/bin directory.

I think it is an executable permissions error? Because I get output when I do `file java` in the directory:

```
ethan@elirium:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin$ file java
java: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
ethan@elirium:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin$ java
-sh: java: not found
ethan@elirium:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin$ ./java
-sh: ./java: not found
ethan@elirium:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin$
```

These are the permissions of every file in the bin directory:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        140868 Mar 11  2016 apt
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139260 Mar 11  2016 extcheck
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139284 Mar 11  2016 idlj
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13280 Jul 26 20:02 jaotc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 jarsigner
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13144 Jul 26 20:02 java
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2801 Mar 11  2016 java-rmi.cgi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13192 Jul 26 20:02 javac
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13200 Jul 26 20:02 javadoc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        140868 Mar 11  2016 javah
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 javap
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            40 Jul 26 19:59 javaws -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/javaws
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jcmd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13232 Jul 26 20:02 jconsole
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jdb
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 jdeprscan
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jdeps
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jfr
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139252 Mar 11  2016 jhat
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jhsdb
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 jimage
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13192 Jul 26 20:02 jinfo
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13192 Jul 26 20:02 jjs
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13192 Jul 26 20:02 jlink
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13192 Jul 26 20:02 jmap
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jmod
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 jpackage
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jps
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13200 Jul 26 20:02 jrunscript
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139404 Mar 11  2016 jsadebugd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 jshell
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13200 Jul 26 20:02 jstack
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 jstat
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 jstatd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 keytool
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139260 Mar 11  2016 native2ascii
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            38 Jul 26 19:59 orbd -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/orbd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            41 Jul 26 19:59 pack200 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/pack200
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            44 Jul 26 19:59 policytool -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/policytool
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 rmic
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13160 Jul 26 20:02 rmid
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 rmiregistry
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139276 Mar 11  2016 schemagen
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13168 Jul 26 20:02 serialver
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            44 Jul 26 19:59 servertool -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/servertool
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            43 Jul 26 19:59 tnameserv -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/tnameserv
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            43 Jul 26 19:59 unpack200 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-icedtea/jre/bin/unpack200
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139268 Mar 11  2016 wsgen
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139268 Mar 11  2016 wsimport
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        139268 Mar 11  2016 xjc
ethan@elirium:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin$
```

Whats wrong here? What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Can you check if `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` exists ? It's in your `file java`.

Comment: It sounds like one of the required dynamically linked libraries is missing. Run `ldd java` to find which.

Comment: that seems to be the issue, there is no /lib64 folder.

Comment: You should not modify anything in `/usr` outside of `/usr/local` on any modern platform.